# Why is my Wordpress Gutenberg block not working when I try to add a translation?

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to translate a working and tested custom block and I'm finding a weird problem. I have two xampp installations to work local, one at home and one at work, where I manage different projects.

I'm currently in my work project and I'm trying to translate a plugin with some custom Gutenberg blocks which are perfectly working without the translation. I am using this code for a test function:

In /plugin.php

```
function sgpcoreb_load_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain(
        'sgpcoreb',
        false,
        basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages'
    );
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'sgpcoreb_load_textdomain' );

function sgpcoreb_register_scripts() {
    // Register the script
    wp_register_script(
        'sgpcoreb-pagebreak-editor-script',
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'pagebreak/index.js',
        array(),
        filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'pagebreak/index.js' )
    );
    // Register the translation for the above script
    wp_set_script_translations(
        'sgpcoreb-pagebreak-editor-script',
        'sgpcoreb',
        plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'languages'
    );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_assets', 'sgpcoreb_register_scripts' );

function sgpcoreb_register_blocks() {
    register_block_type_from_metadata(
        dirname(__FILE__) . '/pagebreak/block.json',
        array(
            'editor_script' =\> 'sgpcoreb-pagebreak-editor-script',
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'sgpcoreb_register_blocks' );
```

In /pagebreak/block.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 3,
    "name": "sgpcoreb/pagebreak",
    "title": "Page Break for Print",
    "icon": "editor-break",
    "category": "layout",
    "version": "1.0",
    "textdomain": "sgpcoreb",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style.css"
}
```

In /pagebreak/index.js

```
( function( blocks, i18n, element, blockEditor, ) {
    var __ = i18n.__;
    var el = element.createElement;

    var useBlockProps = blockEditor.useBlockProps;

    blocks.registerBlockType( 'sgpcoreb/pagebreak', {
        title: __( 'Page Break for Print', 'sgpcoreb' ),
        description: __( 'Inserts a page break for printing only.', 'sgpcoreb' ),

        edit: function( props ) {
            return el( 'div',
                useBlockProps( { className: props.className } ),
                el( 'span',
                    {},
                    __( 'Page break for print only', 'sgpcoreb' )
                )
            );
        },

        save: function( props ) {
            return el( 'div',
                useBlockProps.save( { className: props.className } )
            );
        }
    });
})(
    window.wp.blocks,
    window.wp.i18n,
    window.wp.element,
    window.wp.blockEditor,
);
```

In /pagebreak/index.asset.php

```
<?php return
    array( 'dependencies' =>
        array(
            'wp-blocks',
            'wp-i18n',
            'wp-element',
            'wp-block-editor'
        ),
        'version' => '0.1'
    );
```

I have created the .po and .mo files and used wp-cli to create the json file which I renames to `/languages/sgpcoreb-es_ES-sgpcoreb-pagebreak-editor-script.json`.

When I use this plugin at home, it is working as expected, with the translations applied.

Right now at work this is returning me a 'block is not compatibile' error. I have tried to disable all the plugins, to revert to a default theme, with no luck, checked the console which has no errors, and I don't know where else to look at.